# How to change a template location for render_to_string method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, ruby-on-rails-7, render-to-string

I know render_to_string method searches a template in views folder by default, but can this be changed? I mean, does the template have to be located in the views folder or not? I don't like to have some XML templates in the views.

Now my template is in `views/domains/fulfillment/template.xml.erb`,
but I would prefer not to have it in views like `app/domains/fulfillment/template.xml.erb`.

My current code:

```
def query(params:, file_path:)
    ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
      layout: false,
      template: "app/domains/fulfillment/#{file_path}",
      locals: params,
    ).strip
  end
```

I am getting an `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error now, when the its not in the views folder.

I have tried only to changed the template parameter in render_to_string method and can't find how to change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `file:` option to specify an absolute path to a file instead of using the view paths:

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
  layout: false,
  file: Rails.root.join("app", "domains", "fulfillment", file_path)
  locals: params,
).strip
```

Comment: This is a bad idea though as you're just adding potential developer confusion with no apparent advantages. Rails is a convention driven framework - don't violate the conventions unless  you have a convincing reason to do so.